# Why do the No Game No Life anime show different scenes from the Studio Ghibli movies?

Tags: no-game-no-life, studio-ghibli

For example, in episode 5 of *No Game No Life*, there is a scene from the *Castle in the Sky*; and in episode 7, there is a scene from the movie *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind*.

Could it be that the creator himself was a fan of Studio Ghibli? I haven't seen the entire series but I'm sure there are many more scenes from this studio

Answer (score 2):

No Game No Life references a whole lot of anime and games, but you likely are only familiar with Ghibli, so you didn't recognize all the others.

Ep03: Gyakuten Saiban

[image] [image]

Ep05: Akiba Trip, Steins;Gate, Persona 4

[image]

Ep07: Doraemon, Yuugi-ou and Shin Seiki Evangelion

[image] [image] [image]

Ep08: Meitantei Conan

[image] [image]

Ep12: Jojo na Kimyou na Bouken

[image]